# Drive letters in RDP with %~d

Tags: windows, batch-file, rdp

In an rdp session `%~d0` in batch files returns an UNC-path.
What can I do that `%~d0` returns a drive letter instead ?

Comment: `pushd %0` might be useful.  But what exactly do you mean by "patch file"?

Comment: "patch files"= *.bat and *.cmd   I am not looking for a substitution of %~d0.   This expression is contained in several .cmd - files which I don't want to edit.   They work fine when started directly at the server, but when started via rdp then %~d0 returns "\\myserver..." instead of "d:"

Comment: This is not an RDP issue. You can get the same behavior when you run the script directly via a UNC: `\\myserver\share\script.cmd` - no RDP involved at all. You cannot get `%~d0` to return a drive letter because the script is not running from a drive letter.

Comment: ... so, you'll have to change the way you're running the batch scripts in question.  One way to do that would be to write a short batch script that uses `pushd` to map a  drive letter and then runs the existing script.

Comment: Isn't there a way to configure the rdp-client to behave like beeing local ?